# How to check enums from CTO file in an if statement in logic.js file

Tags: hyperledger-composer

If I have a simple enum in the .cto file like:

```
enum STATUS {
    o ACTIVE
    o INACTIVE
}
```

And a user

```
participant User identified by name{
    o String name
    o STATUS status
}
```

How do I check the status in a function like:

```
transaction isActive {
    o User user
}
```

In the logic.js file would I have code like:

```
return getParicipantRegistry(NS + '.User'){
    .then(function(userRegistry) {
        var u = userRegistry.get(user.name)
        if (u.isActive == 'ACTIVE')
            //some code
    })
```

My situation is a little more complicated (enum with 6 types) but I tried to simplify it so the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

change User in transaction to a relationship

```
transaction isActive{
-->User user
}
```

Now in logic.js you can get the status of the user like

```
    /**
     * checkStatus
     * @param {org.test.isActive} checkStatus // use your namespace instead of org.test
     * @transaction
     */
    function checkStatus(txParams){
      // txParams are the parameters given when the transaction is submitted
      // you can access user details by txParams.user
      if(txParams.user.status == "ACTIVE"){
        // do something
      }
     // then you can update the user by 
     return getParticipantRegistry(NS+'.User').then(function(userRegistry){
          // or you can also check status directly here and do something
          return userRegistry.update(txParams.user)
      })

    }
```